# Unsupported configuration attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] when upgrade from 3.2.6 to 4.0.1

Tags: spring-security

Got the following error when I try to upgrade spring-security from 3.2.6 to 4.0.1. Checked the migration guide but nothing about `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` not compatible. Any idea?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [9]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5162)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [9]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:175)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 51 more
```

security.xml

```
    <http pattern="/accounts/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthSecuredAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/accounts/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<http pattern="/secured/**" create-session="never" entry-point-ref="oauthSecuredAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/system/secured/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
      xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <anonymous enabled="false"/>
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like they have changed the default value of the `use-expressions` attribute from `false` to `true`. When I changed it to `false`, it worked for me.